# H2 Database reads data in ascending Order, needs to insertion order

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, h2

Spring boot in-memory H2 data base reads data in ascending order, whereas I've tested the same data using oracle it reads data in insertion. how to make h2 database read data in insertion order?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If your SELECT statement does not specify ORDER BY clause explicitely, that means you do not care about order, and it is implementation-dependant and non-deterministic. There is no way to match order in database X vs. database Y, Even in a single database, different runs may produce different results. Fix you query if you care about order, or build your test to compare unordered collections, if you don't.
And if you really need "insertion order" than use column populated by SEQUENCE values for ordering.